# How to force ActiveRecord not to escape special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have found strange behavior with ActiveRails,

when I am creating a record with some model, and setting some text property to "1&amp;2", then it is converted to "1&amp;amp2" for some reason.

Console request:

> Data.new :name => "1&amp;2"

Results from console:

> Data ..., name: "1&amp;amp;2", ...

How could I force rails not to process special symbols ?

regards

Comment: It should work. What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 3.2.12, pretty much stuck with this issue. '&' being changed to a '&amp;' always.

Comment: Did you try to use single quotes instead of double? :name => '1&amp;2'

Comment: Yep. It's what I thought first, that it has been interpolated with double quotes. But no, no difference.

Comment: It looks like  CGI.unescapeHTML() solves this ! But I still not truly understand why ... the string was not changing before the call, it looks like it was drivers or db who is changing the data. Strange.